# Where do I talk to people about the Game Jam?

Tags: discussion

I'm wanting to have a try at the Summer Game Jam.
At the moment I have an idea of what to try, but aren't sure of how to implement it, however that's not the point of my question.

Having never participated in one of these before I think it would be useful to be able to talk to other people who are participating.

Is there a specific chat room for this, or some other discussion area?
Is it OK to put up questions on the main GDSE page, or will that be considered spamming?

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: There's always the GDSE chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development Do derail us if we're talking about off topic stuff :)

Answer (score 5):

I think that's a good topic for the chatroom.

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development

Answer (score 2):

Ask questions about the jam in meta or in chat. Chat will likely get you answers faster but which tool you choose is up to you.

Do not ask questions about the jam on the main site. You may use the main site for asking questions for issues you are having while developing your game for the jam. Keep in mind there are not special rules for game jam game dev questions and your question must still follow the rules outlined in the help center. When in doubt, as others have pointed out, just head over to chat and ask away.

Happy jamming!